# how to get hot reload to work with React with Dotnet and Docker

Tags: javascript, c#, reactjs, docker, .net-core

I'm trying to get hot reload to work with React, Docker and Dotnet.

However, from what i found on the internet
only static rendering works with docker.

So i have to do

`docker -t build {Name_of_file}`
everytime to see changes within React....

I'm sure there's a way to do this,

here's my dockerfile.

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0 AS build

RUN curl --silent --location https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_10.x | bash -
RUN apt-get install --yes nodejs

# Copy the source from your machine onto the container.
WORKDIR /src
COPY . .


RUN dotnet restore "./dotnet-test.csproj"

RUN dotnet publish "dotnet-test.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0

# Expose port 80 to your local machine so you can access the app.
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443


COPY --from=build /app/publish .

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "dotnet-test.dll"]
```

If anyone has a github that does this let me know (:

**Future me here!! Here is a link of me doing this with https**

https://easyrun32.medium.com/net-5-react-docker-nginx-mysql-https-hotreload-50d87b32d492

Comment: Why are you trying to use docker for running a debugging session? usually the way this is done is you run you "react portion" with node, yarn start etc... on VS Code for example... and the C# portion in Visual Studio .... docker is more for like running things you are not debugging.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: Not sure if this solution will work but give it a shot

#### Summary:

1. Use only the sdk image (runtime image won't work).
2. Use `dotnet watch`
3. Update `.csproj` file to include files to be watched

#### Long answer:

**1. New Dockerfile**

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0 AS build

RUN curl --silent --location https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_10.x | bash -
RUN apt-get install --yes nodejs

# Copy the source from your machine onto the container.
WORKDIR /src
COPY . .


RUN dotnet restore "./dotnet-test.csproj"

RUN dotnet publish "dotnet-test.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish


# Expose port 80 to your local machine so you can access the app.
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

WORKDIR /app/publish
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "watch", "dotnet-test.dll"]
```

**2. Project File Changes**

```
<ItemGroup>
    <!-- extends watching group to include *.js files -->
    <Watch Include="**\*.js" Exclude="node_modules\**\*;**\*.js.map;obj\**\*;bin\**\*" />
</ItemGroup>
```

This should work for the most part. Make quick updates to include/exclude more files.